# How to execute a Python program in PHP and use the return value inside HTML <p/>?

Tags: python, php, html, return

How would I go about executing Python code from PHP? I belive `shell_exec(Command)` will run a command from the terminal. I have tried this so far:

```
<?php 

$command = escapeshellcmd('python3 main.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```

In main.py it will return a value which is `return randomname`, I would like to put this in a `<p>` tag in my website.

Comment: There is also, an error in line :
    
"$command = escapeshellcmd('main.py'); "
in order to execute a python script you need escapeshellcmd('python main.py') or escapeshellcmd('python3 main.py') --depends on python version you that you need

Comment: Is that for executing it in the terminal?

Comment: yes, because in the above code you are setting up a command which through the PHP's function shell_exec() it will be executed in the terminal (shell).

Comment: My question is how would i show on my webpage, the variable that python returns? @TassosK

Comment: There is an answer bellow from @Dennis that it works. You must be more careful when you ask a question, in this case, yours is "How to execute Python program in PHP" AND " return value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Easy and quick way

To wrap your $output variable into paragraph tags you could do this.

```
echo "<p>$output</p>";
```

## More modular and reusable

If you want to include this in your template, you could put your php code into a function and then call it from your template. But here, don't echo the value, return it instead.

```
<?php
function getData()
{
    $command = escapeshellcmd('main.py');
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    return $output;
}
?>
```

And then call your function from your template.

```
<p><?php echo getData(); ?></p>
```

Comment: It should actually work like this. Did you use the double quotes around the echo? Single quotes would echo the variable as you've stated.

Comment: My code is now this: 
<php>
function getData()
{
    $command = escapeshellcmd('main.py');
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    return $output;
}
</php>

<p><?php echo getData(); ?></p> It is just showing on the screen this: (on my webpage) function getData() { $command = escapeshellcmd('main.py'); $output = shell_exec($command); return $output; }

Comment: Don't use `<php>`, this does not exist. Simply use `<?php` as the starting tag and `?>` as the ending tag. I have added the php tags to my answer. And make sure you are doing all this in a .php file and your webserver runs php.

Comment: I changed it and it does the same as it did last time. Do i need to add or remove anything else?

Comment: Then this seems to be a problem with your setup. 
Is php code generally being executed? You could simply test this by putting 
`<?php echo "hello world"; ?>` into a php file and checking if it returns an output. 
If not, then you need to check your local php environment. Maybe you can use something like `MAMP`, `XAMP` or even `docker` to run your local web server.

Comment: I don't think i had php installed. I just ran sudo apt install php and it is installing it now. There is no output.